# get review rating bubble from tripadvisor

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

how to get review from tripadvisor

this my code using beautifulsoup

```
review_data = data.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'reviews-tab'})

for review in review_data:
    namareview = review.findNext('a', attrs={'class':'ui_header_link social-member-event-MemberEventOnObjectBlock__member--35-jC'})[0].text.strip()
    ratingreview =
    tittlereview = data.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'location-review-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText--2tFRT'})[0].text.strip()
    print (namareview)
```

and how to get value rating review from bubble rating

```
<span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_30"></span>
```

this my code now

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g297722-d6611509-Reviews-Pahawang_Island-Bandar_Lampung_Lampung_Sumatra.html"
response = requests.get(url)
data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(data.title.text)
nama = data.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':'ui_header h1'})[0].text.strip()
print (nama)
category = data.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'attractions-attraction-review-header-AttractionLinks__detail--2-xvX'})[0].text.strip()
print (category)
location= data.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'attractions-contact-card-ContactCard__contactRow--3Ih6v'})[0].text.strip()
print (location)
review_data = data.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'reviews-tab'})
for review in review_data:
    namareview = review.findNext('a', attrs={'class':'ui_header_link social-member-event-MemberEventOnObjectBlock__member--35-jC'})[0].text.strip()
    bubblereview=
    tittlereview = data.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'location-review-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText--2tFRT'})[0].text.strip()
    print (namareview,bubblereview,tittlereview)
```

thistime my full code

Comment: Could you show me a minimal example of your code?(Your website?)

Comment: Include the URL

Comment: Are you just trying to get all the reviews for the location (the stuff on the bottom of the page?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tripadvisor is a tricky site to scrape. But not impossible. Not sure what you are after, but you can work/look at parsing the json within the script tags:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import re
import json




url = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g297722-d6611509-Reviews-Pahawang_Island-Bandar_Lampung_Lampung_Sumatra.html"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
print(data.title.text)
nama = data.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':'ui_header h1'})[0].text.strip()
print (nama)
category = data.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'attractions-attraction-review-header-AttractionLinks__detail--2-xvX'})[0].text.strip()
print (category)
location= data.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'attractions-contact-card-ContactCard__contactRow--3Ih6v'})[0].text.strip()
print (location)

# Get Total count of reviews
data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

reviewDataIDs = []
scripts = data.find_all('script')
for script in scripts:
    if 'window.__WEB_CONTEXT__=' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text
        jsonStr = jsonStr.split('window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:')[-1]

        iterateJson = True
        while iterateJson == True:
            try:
                jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr + '}')
                iterateJson = False
            except:
                jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('}',1)[0]


raiseError = True
for k, v in jsonData['urqlCache'].items():
    try:
        totalCount = jsonData['urqlCache'][k]['data']['locations'][0]['reviewListPage']['totalCount']  
        raiseError = False
        reviewDataIDs.append(k)
        break
    except:
        pass




def getJsonData(reviewCount, reviewDataIDs, continueLoop):
    while continueLoop == True:
        url = "https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Attraction_Review-g297722-d6611509-Reviews-or%s-Pahawang_Island-Bandar_Lampung_Lampung_Sumatra.html#REVIEWS"  %reviewCount   
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        data = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

        scripts = data.find_all('script')
        for script in scripts:
            if 'window.__WEB_CONTEXT__=' in script.text:
                jsonStr = script.text
                jsonStr = jsonStr.split('window.__WEB_CONTEXT__={pageManifest:')[-1]

                iterateJson = True
                while iterateJson == True:
                    try:
                        jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr + '}')
                        iterateJson = False
                    except:
                        jsonStr = jsonStr.rsplit('}',1)[0]


        raiseError = True
        for k, v in jsonData['urqlCache'].items():
            try:
                reviewData = jsonData['urqlCache'][k]['data']['locations'][0]['reviewListPage']['reviews']  
                raiseError = False
                if k not in reviewDataIDs:#
                    continueLoop = False
                    reviewDataIDs.append(k)
                break
            except:
                pass

        if raiseError == True:
            raise ValueError ('Data could not be found.')

        if continueLoop == False:
            return reviewData, reviewDataIDs



# Get Reviews
for reviewCount in list(range(0,totalCount,5)):
    reviewData, reviewDataIDs = getJsonData(reviewCount, reviewDataIDs, continueLoop=True)

    for each in reviewData:
        rating = each['rating']
        title = each['title']
        text = each['text']
        user = each['username']

        print  ('Name: %s\nTitle: %s\nRating: %s\nReview: %s\n' %(user, title, rating, text) + '-'*70 + '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Name: Hamdan O
Title: Great for snorkelling and beach fun
Rating: 4
Review: Get a boat from Ketapang Jetty. There were 4 piers with lots of boats to choose from. Choose from traditional wooden boats which are cheaper but slow paced or higher priced fast fiberglass speed boats. We haggled for a fast speed boat to take us snorkelling and island hopping for half a day at 700K Rupiah. We got it from Pak Yayat at Pier 2. Pahawang is excellent for snorkelling. Just off shore the island the residents built platforms with small food/drink booths. They moored the boats there as bases for snorkelling. You can hop from one platform to another. Fantastic ideas to preserve the corals but unfortunately the inexperienced snorkellers ravaged through some of the patches closer to te beach. Great for an overnight trip as well at some of the local folks' homestays on the island.

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Name: PaulusKK
Title: he Trip is just So So
Rating: 3
Review: the boat trip to Pahawang island to me is a bit unsafe, it was a small wooden boat, and the journey was bumpy with high waves, and the island itself almost have no attraction, and the lunch provided there was not good, I only enjoy the fresh coconut water.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Name: damarwianggo
Title: Pahawang is awesome
Rating: 5
Review: It was a story that Pahawang Island is great place to visit. Then, when I had a chance to accompany students from SMAK IPEKA Palembang to visit Pahawang Island in Lampung, Pahawang is truly exciting. Our one-day-trip to Pahawang was really extraordinary. Moreover, all the students were really excited to join all activities during the trip. The guide helped us to enjoy the trip.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Name: deddy p
Title: Awesome
Rating: 5
Review: One word i can tell about Pahawang..... Superb. Clean water, beautiful corals. Hope you can help to take care this beautiful environment. Keep it clean.....stay away from plastic.
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Name: kristi0308
Title: Clean beach
Rating: 3
Review: I felt like in pulau pari seribu island for the view 
The corals are dead but i saw lots of babies baracudas and a huge purple jellyfish and still got so many pretty little fish
Water are clean and people are not careless about environment as it was very clean when i swam in the island
Thanks to my boat man i paid him only 400k just for a day trip by myself
Paid boat parking every time i move like around 15-20k 
And snorkel gear for 30k
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's a unique number for that url. I'm working on making the code more robust. Give me a few minutes and I'll update the code.

Comment: Ya it's really tricky. It's weird because as you iterate through the pages, sometimes it repeats page 1, and then sometimes it doesn't And then also, page 1 has 2 identifiers. I think I worked it out so that it comes across the same set of 5 reviews, it'll try again, thus giving you all 116 unique reviews.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the bubble rating is represented as the number at the end of the class name. Each bubble has a value of 10, so `ui_bubble_rating bubble_30` is a rating with 3 out of 5 bubbles filled. Likewise `ui_bubble_rating bubble_45` will have 4.5 out of 5 bubbles filled. You can find all these instances with a regex since the number changes.

```
bubblereview = data.find_all('span', {'class': re.compile('ui_bubble_rating bubble_\d*')})
```

The resulting list:

```
[<span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_30"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_50"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_30"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_35"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_45"></span>,
 <span class="ui_bubble_rating bubble_40"></span>]
```

You can filter out the ratings like this:

```
ratings = re.findall('\d+', ''.join(map(str, bubblereview)))
# ['45', '45', '40', '30', '50', '50', '30', '40', '35', '40', '40', '45', '40']
```

Comment: `for review in review_data:
    namareview = review.findNext('a', attrs={'class':'ui_header_link social-member-event-MemberEventOnObjectBlock__member--35-jC'})[0].text.strip()
    bubblereview=data.find_all('span', {'class': re.compile('ui_bubble_rating bubble_\d*')})
    tittlereview = data.find_all('a', attrs={'class':'location-review-review-list-parts-ReviewTitle__reviewTitleText--2tFRT'})[0].text.strip()
    print (namareview,bubblereview,tittlereview)`     why this code no result

Comment: @IlhamPrayudha Are you getting an error or is nothing printing out?

Comment: If nothing is printing is means `review_data` is an empty list, so the for loop has 0 iterations.

Comment: i using this [https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g297722-d6611509-Reviews-Pahawang_Island-Bandar_Lampung_Lampung_Sumatra.html] for crawling and and using class reviews-tab for review_data . is it not quite right  @alec

Comment: Mr HO ['45', '45', '40', '30', '50', '50', '30', '40', '35', '40', '40', '45', '40'] Great for snorkelling and beach fun
Paulus K K ['45', '45', '40', '30', '50', '50', '30', '40', '35', '40', '40', '45', '40'] Great for snorkelling and beach fun
damarwianggo ['45', '45', '40', '30', '50', '50', '30', '40', '35', '40', '40', '45', '40'] Great for snorkelling and beach fun
deddy p ['45', '45', '40', '30', '50', '50', '30', '40', '35', '40', '40', '45', '40'] Great for snorkelling and beach fun                                      this is my result why bubble and tittle is same?

Comment: its doing that because you are pulling the whol list and not iterating through the list

Answer (score 0):

Try this loop:

```
for review in data.select("div[class*='SingleReview']"):
    title= review.select_one(":scope a > span > span").get_text()
    buble_tag = review.select_one(":scope span[class*='bubble']")
    raiting = buble_tag["class"][-1].split("_")[-1]
    print(f"({raiting}){title}")
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works and for the only 5 reviews needed per page...

```
 bubblereview = soup.find_all('div', {'class': re.compile('nf9vGX55')})
```